# How to make my peripherals connected through monitor be detected by laptop

Tags: usb, laptop, audio, hdmi, external-display

I have a setup where I have a laptop and computer that I use regularly with the same monitor.  Until now I have always switched the radio reciever for my headphones, and the wireless reciever for my keyboard between the two machines by unplugging them and plugging them into the necessary computer.  I now have a monitor which has two HDMI ports, a USB type C port and two USB 3 ports.  I want that I can plug the two recievers for the keyboard and headphones into the monitor and that they will "automatically" be detected by the computer and/or laptop depending on which input is selected as active.

At the moment both the computer and laptop are connected to the monitor via an HDMI cable.  The Desktop is also connected via a USB Type C cable as well.  Currently, the desktop "works".  When I turn it on both the keyboard and headphones can be used.  When I turn on my laptop and switch the input on the monitor, neither the keyboard. nor the headphones are detected.  When I plug the recievers directly into the laptop the devices work.

I think this is quite a common thing to do, but I am unsure as to why this fails to work with my laptop, but does work with my desktop.  Both are running up-to-date versions of Windows 10.

Edit: The hardware I have is:

- Monitor: LG-32UN880
- Keyboard: Logitech G915 wireless keyboard
- Headphones: Steel Series Arctis 7

Comment: I don't use USB hubs on monitors so I can't answer your question, but I think it will help if you mention the exact type of monitor you're using.

Comment: The reason it works with your desktop is because you have the USB from the monitor connected to it. You would need to connect that USB to your laptop instead for that to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB on the monitor goes down the USB cable, not down the HDMI. HDMI cannot tell a PC to connect specific ports up.

If you want to swap USB between two machines then you will need some kind of USB switching device [like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01N6GD9JO) that has two ports to connect to two different computers and four ports to connect your peripherals.